# Regex in a python script

Tags: python, regex

My regex is horrendous. I have list items that look like this

```
device = ['1U1abc']
device = ['18U12def']
```

I want to split the item out that it will look like this

```
device = ['1','U1','abc']
device = ['18','U12','def']
```

So i have an entry for the first number in the string, the code with a letter and number, and the second code containing all letters. Is regex a good method to get this?

Comment: So you are looking to break the string up on digit/nondigit boundaries, is that right?

Comment: @BoarGules that's right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(^\d+|U\d+|[a-z]+)', device[0])
['1', 'U1', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Regex**.

**Demo:**

```
import re
device = ['1U1abc', '18U12def']
for i in device:
    m = re.search("(?P<firstValue>\d+)(?P<secondVal>U\d+)(?P<thirdVal>\w+)", i)
    if m:
        print(m.group('firstValue'))
        print(m.group('secondVal'))
        print(m.group('thirdVal'))
        print("-------------")
```

**Output:**

```
1
U1
abc
-------------
18
U12
def
-------------
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import re

devices = ['1U1abc', '18U12def']
rex = '(\d+)(\w\d+)(\w+)'
r = re.compile(rex)
[r.findall(device) for device in devices]
```

So. i guess you will handle a list of string, it could be convenient. Use regex101.com to made up and check a regex. Precompile it cos it can save you time with huge list for parsing.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Can you say something about how this works and why it would solve the problem?